# Is there a real world equivalent to Tak?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle

What is the game of Tak, from *The Wise Man's Fear* (introduced to Kvothe by Bredan in Vintas), closest to (if anything) in our world?

Quotes from the author preferred over pure guesswork.

Comment: I'm interested to know what additional info you would want before marking my (or anyone elses) answer as "accepted"

Comment: I don't know if you've found this or not as I seem to be a year or so late, but apparently there are actual rules now, if you head over to reddit.com/r/tak there are a variety of links to play and read the rules for tak, as well as downloadable games you can face off against ai in.

Comment: My answer feels pretty comprehensive, especially after the latest update. Is there anything else you'd like to see addressed before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 16):

### Yes, there is (finally!)

**UPDATE #3:** As mentioned by Alex in his [comment above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54411/alex), Patrick Rofuss has now (as of October 2015) released a **publicly available set of rules and a downloadable board** which you can find [here](http://www.cheapass.com/games/tak)

> *"Tak will be in open beta until roughly February 2016. Shortly
>   thereafter, we will launch a Kickstarter project to manufacture the
>   game. We will be shooting for a $40 boxed game, with pieces and a 6x6
>   board, and we might also make a $25 "Traveler's Bag" with a 5x5 set
>   inside, but no board. These prices are complete guesses, because we
>   don't yet know much about making pieces like this."*

---

<s>**UPDATE #2:** As of July 2015, the game is in prototype stage, [according to the book's author](http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/2015/06/a-blog-of-three-parts/);</s>

> Still not convinced? I’ll bring along my **prototype Tak set** and we’ll
>   play a game. A beautiful game.

---

<s>**UPDATE #1 -** As of March 2014, Patrick Rothfuss has managed to successfully fund a [kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/cheapassgames/pairs-a-new-classic-pub-game/posts/756249) to create a "Rules of Tak" alongside various sets of Magic/Gathering cards; Again, it's  clear that it's similar to 'go' but not identical (and also that he doesn't have real rules for it (yet)).</s>

> Tak is a board game featured prominently in The Wise Man's Fear. **It's
>   a classic strategy game comparable to chess or go**. And **we'd like to
>   make a real set of rules for it.**

He also published this photo alongside the Kickstarter:

[image]

<s>The game of Tak appears to be at least partially based on the classic Chinese game of [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) however it's made clear in [this February blog post](http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/2014/02/a-pair-of-kickstarters-and-kickstarting-pairs/) that the author hasn't actually developed real rules for it (yet);</s>

> It’s pieces on a board, and largely tactical, as opposed to having a
>   strong random element.
>
> P.S. Okay. One final thing. When I was talking with James last night,
>   he mentioned that as a game designer, **the thought of designing a game
>   like Tak was really interesting to him**.